# displaying ckeditor saved html data from database to normal text in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am using ckeditor to write posts and saving that data in sql server 2008.
in database it is saving data in html form.

I want to display data saved in database to a aspx page as a plain text.in database post saved as:

```
<p>haskdbn</p>

<p>sakaksfb asknzxv</p>
```

In my asp.net page the data have to display as normal form without tags.

I write code behind:

```
revolutionEntities obj = new revolutionEntities();
var v = from p in obj.posts orderby p.postedtime select new { p.post1 };
foreach (var item in v)
{
   HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(item.ToString());
}
GridView1.DataSource = v;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

but its not decoding. its sghowing the same text as it is in html form

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating you data source in `foreach` loop.

You can use a for loop on your source as follows
**Not tested**

```
 for (int i=0;i<item.Count;i++)
 {
       v[i]= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(l[i].ToString());
 }
```

### Edit 1

```
revolutionEntities obj = new revolutionEntities();
var list = (from p in obj.posts orderby p.postedtime select new { p.post1 }).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i]= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(list[i].ToString());
}
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: I tried your code but it is showing an error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'AnonymousType#1'" at HttpUtility

Answer (score 0):

```
GridView1.DataSource = obj.posts.OrderBy(p1=>p1.postedtime)
                        .Select(p=>HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(p.post1.ToString()))
                        .ToList();  
GridView1.DataBind();
```